# Idiom for smart_ptr's and virtual functions

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, smart-pointers, virtual-functions

In a code I'm writing, I want to rely as much as possible on smart pointers. I have now the problem, that when I want to use dynamic dispatch (which is basically not a problem with smart pointers), in the virtual function that gets called, `this` is again a bare pointer and is stripped of all the smart pointer info.

To make this clear, consider the following base class

```
class Base {
  virtual smart_ptr<Base> do_stuff(int some_param);
}
```

and a fragment where this class and a derived class is used;

```
smart_ptr<Base> ptr = smart_ptr<Base>( new Derived(param1) );
smart_ptr<Base> foo = ptr->do_stuff(2);
```

For the `do_stuff` implementation in `Derived` it should be possible to return just the original smart pointer, or a new smart pointer wrapping the old one or even a completely new object. Of course, when I say "the original smart pointer" it doesn't have to be the same object, but it needs to link to the same  administrative info (like ref counter, or linked list or whatever) as `ptr`. I clearly won't get that using `smart_ptr<Base>(this)`, but what are the alternatives?  The only alternatives that I currently see, are

1. Pass the smart pointer also into `do_stuff` like `do_stuff(smart_ptr<Base> This, int some_param)`, assert that `this == This.get()` and then work with `This`?
2. Keep the smart pointers in a global hashtable (or static member in Base) and make a lookup in `do_stuff` into that table (like `This = Base::ptrs[this]`)?

Both of them are pretty ugly. The first can be made a bit nicer by

3. Renaming `do_stuff` to `do_stuff_`, making it protected and providing a friend function `do_stuff(smart_ptr<Base> ptr, int param)`, which returns `ptr->do_stuff_(ptr, param)`.

However, I don't like that friend function business for methods that should rather be class members. Is there any nice C++ idiom out there that I've seen yet? It should preferable work with C++03.

Comment: Simple: Don't return `this` from a function. Since you just called the function, you must have a way to access the object after all... (There is one exception for [fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C.2B.2B) in which you will return `*this` and only ever use that to chain another method.)

Comment: "but it needs to link to the same administrative info" are you saying this because you need to track the relationship between `foo` and `ptr` or is `foo` some kind of transformation of `ptr`?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `std::shared_from_this` and `std::make_shared`.

Comment: @Guvante Well, if e.g. `foo` contains a smart pointer to the same object (`new Derived(param)`) that as `ptr` and both have there own reference counter, the code will probably at some point reference an already deleted object, and it will delete the object twice. So, they *must* use the same reference counter. I just said 'administrative info` because, you need not realise this via reference counting.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, that looks quite nice. With boost it should also work with C++03.

Comment: @gha.st The function may return `this`, but may also return some kind of wrapper or a completely new object. The calling code cannot know this, since this is completely up to the derived class.

Comment: So you are sometimes returning `this` (in a smart pointer) other times you are returning some other object. That is the bit that I was missing. @Deduplicator: You should expand your comment to an answer, it matches his use case quite well.